# Tomcat server getting restarted frequently

Tags: tomcat, shell, shell-scripting

We have a script like below to monitor our server. During this code our server getting restarted. Can anyone please explain the meaning of below script?

```
if [ -f $HOME/catalinamonitor ]; then
  echo JVM failed;
  export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.6.0
  $HOME/jakarta-tomcat/bin/shutdown.sh
  sleep 30
  /usr/bin/killall -9 java 2>/dev/null
  $HOME/jakarta-tomcat/bin/startup.sh
  rm -f $HOME/catalinamonitor
  exit 1
fi
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the file `$HOME/catalinamonitor` exists, write `JVM failed` to the screen. Put the value `/usr/java/jdk1.6.0` in `JAVA_HOME` and make it an environment variable.

Run the script in `$HOME/jakarta-tomcat/bin/shutdown.sh`, wait 30 seconds and kill all processes that are `java`. All output will be redirected to `/dev/null` (not shown on screen).

Run the following script `$HOME/jakarta-tomcat/bin/startup.sh` and delete the file `rm -f $HOME/catalinamonitor`. Terminate the script with an error (1).

So basically, If a file exists, kill all tomcat and java, then restart it and delete the file.

Comment: Thanks !!! Any idea `catalinamonitor` would create automcaticaly? If so at which case

Comment: Probably it's a file created by another script after doing a check (probably some sort of check on the tomcat-server). Maybe something in the same script?

Comment: the script file has like this `touch $HOME/catalinamonitor`, this executes every 10 mins. Apart from this we dont have anything related to catalinamonitor

Comment: And when does it do the `touch $HOME/catalinamonitor`? That is when the script says it's necessary to restart the tomcat-server.

Comment: The first part of the script is what I have mentioned in the question, Second part has touch command. Both are in same script file which will be excuted every 10 mins as set in cron job

Comment: Then it's basically telling to restart the service every 10 minutes. IF you want to get rid of it, remove the `touch`-command.

Answer (score 2):

A *way* better solution is to use [YAJSW](http://yajsw.sourceforge.net/) or similar as a watchdog. I cringed at the killall...